# The conversion could not be completed because the supplied DateTime did not have the Kind property set correctly

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I am trying convert UK time into UTC in C#

```
DateTime utc = DateTime.UtcNow;
var ukTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
DateTime ukTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utc,ukTimeZone, TimeZoneInfo.Local );

Console.WriteLine(ukTime);
```

But I got this error.

> Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: The conversion could
> not be completed because the supplied DateTime did not have the Kind
> property set correctly.  For example, when the Kind property is
> DateTimeKind.Local, the source time zone must be TimeZoneInfo.Local.
> (Parameter 'sourceTimeZone')
> at System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone, TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone,
> TimeZoneInfoOptions flags, CachedData cachedData)
> at System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone, TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone)

But if I run the below code

```
DateTime time = new DateTime(2022, 11, 09, 23, 47, 00);
var ukTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
DateTime ukTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(time,ukTimeZone, TimeZoneInfo.Local );
Console.WriteLine(ukTime);
```

I got the expected result: `11/09/2022 23:47:00`

Why does this error occur? What is the difference between `time` and `utc`?

Comment: In your first example, the first parameter you're setting to `ukTimeZone` is the source time zone, but it's incorrect. Although GMT and UTC are effectively the same, GMT is considered a local timezone in C#, but UTC is it's own category altogether. You should instead either pass `TimeZoneInfo.Utc` as the source, or use the method `ConvertTimeFromUtc` rather than `ConvertTime`.

Comment: What you say you are trying to do, and what your code is doing, are very different. IMHO unless you are always dealing with UTC, or with some abstract time value that is disconnected from any timezone, just use `DateTimeOffset` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The `DateTimeKind` associated with a `DateTime` is determined by how you construct it:

```cs
DateTime.UtcNow.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc
DateTime.Now.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local
new DateTime(2022, 11, 9, 23, 47, 0) == DateTimeKind.Unspecified
```

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime#system-timezoneinfo-converttime(system-datetime-system-timezoneinfo-system-timezoneinfo)) for the `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` method you are calling describes the behavior you are observing:

> #### Exceptions
>
> `ArgumentException`
>
> The `Kind` property of the `dateTime` parameter is `Local`, but the `sourceTimeZone` parameter does not equal `Local`.
>
> -or-
>
> The `Kind` property of the `dateTime` parameter is `Utc`, but the `sourceTimeZone` parameter does not equal `Utc`.
>
> -or-
>
> The `dateTime` parameter is an invalid time (that is, it represents a
> time that does not exist because of a time zone's adjustment rules).

Your first example demonstrates the second reason described for the exception.  That is:

- The `Kind` property of the input value is `DateTimeKind.Utc`
- The source time zone you are passing is `"GMT Standard Time"`, not `"UTC"`

These time zones are not the same.

- `"GMT Standard Time"` corresponds to `"(UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"`
- `"UTC"` corresponds to `"(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time"`

The primary difference being that London uses UTC+1 during the summer months when British Summer Time (a daylight saving time) is in effect.  Reference: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london

Conversely, UTC is not necessarily the time in the UK.  It's a time standard that applies universally to the entire planet.  It never observes daylight saving time.